# Using Split to all new element to ArrayList with mix inputs.

Tags: java, arraylist, split, java.util.scanner

I'm using split to divide up a string input. The first 3 work good cause they are strings but the last input is a double. Any idea how I should go about making this work so the string split can then pass the result[4] to the double in the ArrayList?

```
Scanner catin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the Name, Breed, Color, and Weight of the Cat: ");
String test = catin.nextLine();
String[] result = test.split(","); 
Cat c4 = new Cat(result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4]);
```

Comment: Give an example of the input you're taking into your `String test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so sure what you want but I think you are after  `Double.parseDouble(result[4])`:

```
Cat cat = new Cat(result[1], result[2], result[3], Double.parseDouble(result[4]));
```

Again be aware of the index. The index should be `0 --> 3` as Arrays are zero based indexed.

Comment: Thank You. The Double.parseDouble was what I was looking for. Also thanks to the reminder about the index, that had slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexes are wrong. Should be:

```
Cat c4 = new Cat(result[1], result[2], result[3], Double.parseDouble(result[4]));
```

Arrays are zero-indexed, and parse your `weight String`.